# How to match all characters in a string and collect multiple groups?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to figure out how to select all the "-on_"s in a specific match using preg_match_all.

I've tried lots of regex patterns but I'm totally stumped. The best regex-er in our company has been working on this for an hour or 2 and can't make any headway either.

This one seems to be most promising `.*(-on_).*` - but only catches the last "-on_" of each match. Also the first match works correctly, but the second match is everything on the page. I don't understand why.

The example of the HTML I'm trying to parse...

```
<span class="RatingStar__bew-avgstars__2enAh">
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-on__28Wmg">★</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-on__2ks1e">★</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-on__2ks1e">★</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-on__2ks1e">★</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
            </div>
        </span>

... more unimportant no-need-to-match code between ...


<span class="RatingStar__bew-avgstars__2enAh">
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-on__28Wmg">★</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-on__2ks1e">★</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-on__2ks1e">★</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-on__2ks1e">★</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B ">
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
                <span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span>
            </div>
        </span>
```

What I'm using to parse it...

```
preg_match_all('~<span class="RatingStar__bew-avgstars__2enAh">.*(-on_).*</div></span>~', $html, $matches)
```

the response I'm getting is not worth much with how large it is so I'll just summarize:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "Perfectly correct match"
    1 => "Match of the rest of the page (not correct)"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "-on_" // Last on in the match
    1 => "-on_" // Last on in the second match
  ]
]
```

for the 2 matches that I should be getting I should get a group of 4 "-on_"s per match with the listed code.

So what I'm actually expecting is:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    0 => "<span class="RatingStar__bew-avgstars__2enAh"><div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B "><span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span><span ▶"
    1 => "<span class="RatingStar__bew-avgstars__2enAh"><div class="RatingStar__be-c-star__24d1B "><span><span class="RatingStar__be-star-off__2ks1e">★</span></span><span ▶"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    0 => ["-on_","-on_","-on_","-on_"] 
    1 => ["-on_","-on_","-on_","-on_"]
  ]
]

Maybe I'm completely missing something here... any advice?
```

Comment: Tried using `.*?`  at least?

Comment: I'm confused. This is what I get when I run your snippet through `preg_match_all`: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/sR9#tab-preg-match-all This is different from the response you've shown. It never "matches the rest of the page."

Comment: Perhaps using DOMDocument and XPath may be a better solution as it understands the structure and context of what your searching for.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've tried .*? also, still can't seem to get it to work though.

Comment: @Benjamin I didn't include the rest of the document that I'm parsing due to the length of it. If I can figure out a regex that matches 2x on what's listed above it and groups the "-on_" per match it should be sufficient.

Comment: @NigelRen I understand that a Dom Parser may be better but unfortunately I'm working on a large scale project where all the code is already written in this format and I'm just trying to update a small portion. I'll move to a Dom Parser if I must but I'd like to work within the scope of the project if at all possible. This HAS to be solvable via regex.

Comment: @Benjamin Also, you didn't do the regex as I posted it inside of the preg_match_all  - you simply put part of the regex ```.*(-on_).*```

it should have been ```~<span class="RatingStar__bew-avgstars__2enAh">.*(-on_).*</div></span>~```

Comment: (Aside: don't worry about single downvotes. There is no value in asking for feedback, unless you would like readers to guess why someone downvoted. Votes are anonymous by design and there is no obligation on people to explain their votes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is closer to what you want:

```
~<span class="RatingStar__bew-avgstars__2enAh">[\s\S]*?(-on_)[\s\S]*?</div>\s*</span>~
```

You have three problems:

1. `.*` does not match the newline character `\n`. [More info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). You can use `[\s\S]*` instead, which matches every whitespace character and every non-whitespace character (so, every character).
2. The text `</div></span>` does not appear in your snippet. There is whitespace between the `</div>` and the `</span>`. Hence, `</div>\s*?</span>`.
3. You are using the greedy operator `*` rather than the lazy operator `*?`. This is a problem because your entire string ends with `</div></span>`, which means the first match will consume all other matches and proceed to the end of the string.